# How to get all the endpoints/REST paths of a running docker container (404 Errors)

Tags: docker, rest

So I was given a docker image of an application and have it running successfully.

When I go to `http://localhost:8080` on my browser, I can see "alive"

I want to curl some data to it but don't know the endpoint of the url that corresponds to the application

Sending a request.post to `http://localhost:8080` just gives me a `405`; Anything else a `404`

How do I know the correct or all application entrypoint url of the application/deployed container?

Comment: You should be able to see things like the URL routing in the application source code.  Can you edit the question to include a [mcve]?

Answer (score 0):

First of all you posted (I suppose) a wrong url. It should be http://localhost:8080 .

The **endpoints**, better to call them **rest paths**, depend on the application itself.

**Usually** (not all the times) a REST application publishes its **contract** by the URI http://localhost:8080/application.wadl (**WADL** stands for Web Appplication Description Language), but I suggest to look at source code (if you can access it) or ask for documentation.

Comment: Thanks, yes it was http://localhost:8080, I updated the question. I do have access to the source code and I tried out different combinations for the url rest paths but couldn't get to a correct one. `application.wadl` also returns a 404.

Comment: As I stated in my post, you have to ask to service developers or rely on the source code.